# MFC application gui hangs when some data processing

Tags: user-interface, mfc

I have application with GUI but it hangs, when i'am clicking the button that actually does all work. What to do to make it run normally and displaying gui changes "online"?

Comment: Offload processing to a worker thread. Your GUI code is single threaded (I hope, anyway).

Comment: And how it will update some main window information then?

Comment: Interthread communication. Both questions have been answered beyond any imaginable level of detail on this site.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to work with background threads and it's a loop of some kind taking so long, you could add this member function to your UI code and call it in the loop:

```
void CMyDlg::PumpMessages()
{
    // Must call Create() before using the dialog
    ASSERT(m_hWnd!=NULL);

    MSG msg;
    // Handle dialog messages
    while(PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE))
    {
      if(!IsDialogMessage(&msg))
      {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);  
      }
    }
}
```